# Convert a SelectListItem Object to HTML

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following method that gets executed via an AJAX callback. I would like to sometimes return the raw HTML instead of the actual object.

Is that possible?

```
[HttpPost]
public List<SelectListItem> HydrateDivisionsSelectFromDistrict(string distId)
{
    var httpStatus = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    // Returns List<SelectListItem>
    var r = Utility.DataHelper.GetDivisionList(distId,"");

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Return a partial view instead then

Comment: As @asawyer said, return a partial view. Or you can return JSON and build the drop down list client side.